# Count of strictly increasing sequence of integers

Tags: arrays, algorithm, computer-science

You are given two list of integers a and b of same length n, Find the count of strictly increasing sequences of integers
I[0] < I[1] < ..  < I[n-1] such that min(a[i], b[i]) <= I[i] <= max(a[i], b[i]) for each i.
Eg.

````
a = [6,3,4,4]
b = [1,5,1,6]
Four possible solutions are possible
[1 3 4 5],
[1 3 4 6],
[2 3 4 5],
[2 3 4 6].
The length of both arrays will not exceed 100. 
Each element is between 1 and 10000.```

Can someone provide a hint for this question? I am not able to figure out
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dynamic programming approach here. The states of your DP will be the current index and last value ,like `count_sequence(int index, int last_value)` , loop through `min(a[index], b[index])` to `max(a[index], b[index])` ,if there is a value greater then last_value go to next index with current value like `count_sequence(index+1, current_value)`, if you reach base case which is `index>=n` that means you find a sequence then **return 1**. Using this you can find every possible sequence.

With memorization, the complexity will be O(n*m),
*n = array size*, *m = maximum element*

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript/node.js solution:

```js
    const a = [6, 3, 4, 4]
    const b = [1, 5, 1, 6]
    const n = a.length

    let min = []
    let max = []

    for (let i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      let itemMin = (min[i] = Math.min(a[i], b[i]))
      let itemMax = (max[i] = Math.max(a[i], b[i]))

      if (i > 0) {
        const maxBefore = Math.max(a[i - 1], b[i - 1])

        // max of before index, >= current min
        if (maxBefore >= min[i]) {
          itemMin = Math.min(maxBefore + 1, max[i])
        }
      }

      if (i < n - 1) {
        const minAfter = min[i + 1]

        // min of after index, <= current or calculated min
        if (itemMin >= minAfter) {
          itemMin = Math.min(minAfter - 1, min[i])
        }

        // max correction
        itemMax = Math.min(max[i], minAfter - 1)
      }

      // Test is solution possible, if not do something
      if (itemMin < min[i] || itemMin > max[i]) {
        throw new Error('Impossible to solve...')
      }
      if (itemMax < min[i] || itemMax > max[i]) {
        throw new Error('Impossible to solve...')
      }

      // Set min and max values
      min[i] = itemMin
      max[i] = itemMax
    }

    // ***** Printing results
    function printResult(min, max, str = '', item = 0) {
      const n = min.length

      for (let j = min[item]; j <= max[item]; j++) {
        if (item < n - 1) {
          printResult(min, max, `${item !== 0 ? str : ''}${j},`, item + 1)
        } else {
          console.log(`[${str}${j}]`)
        }
      }
    }

    printResult(min, max)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given two arrays, one holding the `min` value and the other the `max` value for each index, you could define a simple recursive function to derive each possible increasing sequence, with the starting value at each position being the maximum of the current `min` value and the previously selected value plus 1.

Here's some Java code to illustrate:

```
static void incSeq(int[] min, int[] max, int[] res, int pos, int prev)
{
    if(pos == min.length)
    {
        System.out.println("seq: " + Arrays.toString(res));
        return;
    }
    
    for(int j = Math.max(prev+1, min[pos]); j <= max[pos]; j++)
    {
        res[pos] = j;
        incSeq(min, max, res, pos+1, j);
    }
}
```

However, if we consider input such as:

```
min = {1,   1,   1,   1}
max = {100, 100, 100, 5}
```

we can see that our function is going to do a lot of useless work iterating through values in the first three positions that will not be part of an increasing sequence.

We can fix this by recognizing that the maximum value we need to consider for position `i` is one less that the max value at position `i+1`. If we start at the last position and work backwards using this rule we can update the `max` array above to:

```
max = {2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Which will mean a lot less work for our recursive function.

Here's the complete code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int n = 4;
    int[] a = {6,3,4,4};
    int[] b = {1,5,1,6};

    int[] min = new int[n];
    int[] max = new int[n];
    
    System.out.println("a:   " + Arrays.toString(a));
    System.out.println("b:   " + Arrays.toString(b));
    
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        min[i] = Math.min(a[i], b[i]);
        max[i] = Math.max(a[i], b[i]);
    }
    
    System.out.println("min: " + Arrays.toString(min));
    System.out.println("max: " + Arrays.toString(max));
    
    // cap max values
    for(int i=n-1; i>0; i--)
    {
        max[i-1] = Math.min(max[i-1], max[i]-1);
    }
    
    System.out.println("max: " + Arrays.toString(max) + "\n");
    
    incSeq(min, max, new int[n], 0, 0);
}

static void incSeq(int[] min, int[] max, int[] res, int pos, int prev)
{
    if(pos == min.length)
    {
        System.out.println("seq: " + Arrays.toString(res));
        return;
    }
    
    for(int j = Math.max(prev+1, min[pos]); j <= max[pos]; j++)
    {
        res[pos] = j;
        incSeq(min, max, res, pos+1, j);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
a:   [6, 3, 4, 4]
b:   [1, 5, 1, 6]
min: [1, 3, 1, 4]
max: [6, 5, 4, 6]
max: [2, 3, 4, 6]

seq: [1, 3, 4, 5]
seq: [1, 3, 4, 6]
seq: [2, 3, 4, 5]
seq: [2, 3, 4, 6]
```